# How do I center something with CSS so that it is centered relative to the scroll bar?

Tags: html, css, centering

I have centered a div on a page for a group project and while the div itself is centered, the websites contents are centered with the scroll bar in mind. What I mean by this is that the web page contents are centered so that the width of the screen is measured without the scroll bars width. So if the monitor was originally 100px wide, it gets read as 100-(scroll bar width) px wide. Unfortunately, this has caused my fixed position div to be a scroll bars width off center from the rest of the site and it looks pretty funky. Any way to fix that? Can't use jquery, can potentially use a little bit of JS.

Here's the link to my site so you can see what I'm talking about. http://51713941.nhd.weebly.com/index.html

Comment: Do you have a link or JSFiddle that you could show?

Comment: Scrollbars are different widths on different operating systems also, so this might not have a solid solution...

Comment: @EnigmaRM updated to include link to site in question. Wish there was a fiddle I could produce for you but Im not even sure how they got the content to center like that in the first place.

Comment: Looks like you got rid of the Glossary issues you were having. Went back to take a look at it, and you've updated the site a bit. IMHO it looks better without the glossary. - Also, if you couldn't tell by my username, the story of the Enigma fascinates me.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see some code.

This can normally be sorted out with css. Margin:auto

You should use the box model concept in css to style and place the content on the site

Again, the question seems rather vague.

Comment: I would give you code but the rest of the site is made in a WYSIWYG editor so it's a mess to sort through. I originally used margin:auto to center but for some reason that didn't work

Comment: So this is done with a cms? What cms? Do you have access to the CSS file or are you writing CSS inline?